# English pangram without Q and W

Tags: pangram

I am looking for the shortest pangram that does not contain the letters Q and W.

The best I can do is "o fat vezir judge my black sphinx", which is a modification of another nice pangram.

Do you know any more english pangram without the letters 'Q' and 'W'?

Comment: Well, technically there's no such thing as a pangram without 'Q' or 'W'...

Comment: let's just say it's an imaginary alphabet that has no Q and W because they are superfluously evil

Comment: i've got a pangram that doesn't use the letters BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry wow, it's a pangram AND an anagram!

Comment: and a palindrome (you probably meant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work, to the extent that short pangrams are always non-sensical and borderline non-grammatical:

> Nymphs frack jug; do vex blitz.

<sub>(24 letters)</sub>

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since it helped me to create this pangram: "vax nymphs blitz frock judge" Thank you!